# How do you know which Licence is needed to use image in your app?

Tags: copyright, licensing

I have created a mobile application and I am using few graphic wallpapers in that. App is free but I am getting some revenue from Google Ads. Can anyone tell me under which licence I can download and use the images for that app.

Answer (score 2):

If you purchased the images from a **stock images website**, when you purchased those images you had a few options to choose from for licensing. Read the details of each license and it will be clear which one you will need.

If you just downloaded the images from **Google Images** or any search engine or website, you might be facing lawsuit(s)... You have to verify that the creator of the image(s) your are using allows you to use them under a license for the usage you need them for.

Another alternative would be to use www.pexels.com where ALL their images are Free for commercial and personal use under the **Creative Commons Zero (CC0) license**.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I am not able to find owners of those images. Is there any way I can check it online?

Answer (score 1):

You can go with copyright free image search like pixabay, pexels, Unsplash, stocksnap.io, Burst and lot more Check this out https://blog.snappa.com/free-stock-photos/ with CC) license

Comment: Where did you get the images from? If there were on Google for example, they were pulled from a website to your google search results. Check with those website.